# Bulk resize / change aspect ratio without image loss

Tags: windows, gratis, images, uploader, instagram

I need to bulk upload images to Instagram but all my images have different aspect ratios.
Basically I need about 20 images to in a 1:1 ratio. I don't want any loss of the original image, so any text at the sides still needs to be there. I don't care if there is a white background, I just need to see all the text. Does anyone know of any software or site that can do this for free without a watermark?

Comment: Are you talking about padding your images with a constant color, so that their dimensions become 1:1? For example, you have a 300x200 pixels image, you add a 300x50 pixels white stripes to its top and bottom, and it becomes a 300x300 image. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Headcrab yes, padding the image so the canvas size is the same ratio on all with the original image centered

Answer (score 1):

Turns out after more searching i found a good program for windows that works
https://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/

Comment: Thanks! I was looking to do the same thing. What I ended up doing to achieve this was resize them to all fit within my desired size (1024x768), then resize the canvas to 1024x768 with my desired background color.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I will add that personally I would use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) for this as it is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform *runs on Linux, Windows, Mac Os X, iOS, Android OS, and others*
- Allows exactly the same operations to be performed on all of the images matching a wildcard from the command line.
- Can do what you are asking for and a lot more